# What could be the format specifier for the below program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer, format-specifiers

```
void TASK(Task100ms_Raster)
{
    int a,b,c;
    struct timespec start, stop;
    uint32 StartTime, StopTime;
    uint32 duration100ms;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
       perror( "clock gettime" );
    }

    StartTime =start.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * start.tv_nsec;
    printf("start time is %lu", StartTime);

    printf("value is %d",c);
    printf("ETAS1\n");
    if( (StopTime = clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)) == -1 )
    {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
    }
    StopTime =  stop.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * stop.tv_nsec;
    printf("stop time is %lu", StopTime);

    duration100ms = StopTime -StartTime;
    printf( "time difference is= %lu\n", duration100ms );
}
```

I created the timer which is calculating the start time, stop time and difference between the time. I am confused about the format specifier for start time, stop time and suration100ms. but struct timespec start, stop; is of type http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/t/timespec.html then what could be the correct format specifiers to get the results. some guide me.

Comment: `uint32` is not a standard type.

Comment: i forgot to add  :typedef unsigned long uint32;

Answer (score 0):

You're doing floating-point calculation to compute number of seconds, but storing the result in an integer:

```
StartTime = start.tv_sec + 0.0000001 * start.tv_nsec;
```

this will truncate the result to whole integers. You should make `StartTime` into a `double`, and print it as such:

```
double StartTime = start.tv_sec + 1e-9 * start.tv_nsec;

printf("start time is %f\n", StartTime);
```

I think it's better for precision, to convert to float when you compute the difference:

```
double duration = StopTime.tv_sec - StartTime.tv_sec +
                  1E-9 * (StopTime.tv_nsec - StartTime.tv_nsec);
```

If you must have the duration as an integer number in units of 100 ms, you could do:

```
duration = 10000 * (StopTime.tv_sec - StartTime.tv_sec) + 
           (StopTime.tv_nsec - StartTime.tv_nsec) / 100000000;
```

Comment: In my case duration is of type uint32;